# Using Hierarchical clustering on a correlation matrix to return k sized subsets of common correlation <x?

Tags: correlation, clustering, python, hierarchical-clustering

I have a 50x50 correlation matrix, and I'd like to avoid directly trying to compute and return all n choose k subsets s.t. the subset of variables have correlation less than some threshold x.   As such, I'd like to create a hierarchical clustering scheme in python s.t:

variable x is related to variable y iff their correlation value is less than X (in my case i'd like to set it to .2). and repeat this process over my entire data set.

I'm currently trying to use the scipy family of functions, but I'm running into some issues with my results (namely, some of my variables in the assigned clusters don't fit my criteria!)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hierarchical clustering is probably what you should look into. You will want complete linkage (so it applies to any pair), and you need to be careful: the implementations may expect a *distance* matrix (and prefer low distance) whereas you supposedly have a similarity matrix, where high values are to be preferred.

But beware that the constraints k clusters *and* a threshold may not be both satisfiable at the same time.

Comment: What about the question "correlation less than X"? How can that be incorporated into your answer?

Comment: thanks fore the responses! 

I'm currently looking for the cluster of least correlated variables for my exploratory analysis and was thinking either complete or single to create them with distance defined as the absolute value of R between them!